# Excel VBA function to recognise Read-Only mode

Tags: vba, excel

I am using some code which opens another file to get data.
This uses a function which I found somewhere called `IsWorkBookOpen` to check if the file is already open.
This code below works well but I am trying to make it work in Read-Only mode.

What I would like to do is only open the file in Read Only mode.
So update the 
`Workbooks.Open FileName:="R:\Development\Copy of Product Information.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True, Password:="bcd"`

I have tried updating this code to open the file in Read Only, but the macro doesn't recognise the file is already open ( in read only mode) and tries to open it again.

```
Ret = IsWorkBookOpen("R:\Development\Copy of Product Information.xlsm")
If Ret = True Then
            Workbooks("Copy of Product Information.xlsm").Activate
            Sheets("Main").Select
Else
        Workbooks.Open FileName:="R:\Development\Copy of Product Information.xlsm", Password:="bcd"
        Sheets("Main").Select
End If
```

The `IsWorkBookOpen` function code:

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

I would like to know a way to modify the `IsWorkBookOpen` to handle Read-Only mode please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work (without needing additional references) and will tell you whether the workbook is open by the application, and whether or not the workbook is readonly. By default, the function will only return true if the workbook is open, and is read-only.

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook

    Dim IteratorWorkbook As Workbook
    For Each IteratorWorkbook In Application.Workbooks
        If IteratorWorkbook.FullName = FileName Then 
            Set TargetWorkbook = IteratorWorkbook
        End If
    Next

    If Not TargetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        If TargetWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
            IsWorkBookOpen = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The loop won't find XLA/XLAM workbooks. Your string comparison is a binary compare. You could exit the loop as soon as your `TargetWorkbook` is set. The `ReadOnly` property only tells you if Excel has opened the file as read-only, not whether the file has a read-only attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, which will tell you if a file is marked as read-only at the file system level, which is not the same as a file opened read-only by an application.

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Function FileIsReadOnly(filePath As String) As Boolean

  Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

  Dim fil As Scripting.File
  Set fil = fso.GetFile(filePath)
  FileIsReadOnly = fil.Attributes And ReadOnly

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening the workbook read-only I guess your function always returns false, unless some other process or user has the file open. If you just need to check if the workbook is open in the current Excel session, you could just use something like:

```
Function IsWorkbookOpen(sWbName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oWb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWb = Workbooks(sWbName)
    IsWorkbookOpen = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Comment: I tried this code but using this function the macro didn't recognise that the file was already open.  I have used one of the other solutions further down the page

Comment: I did mention the limitation: Just check if file is open in the current Excel session. Mind you: the argument the function expects is just the filename, without the path.

Comment: ok, thanks for your solution and comments, i have upvoted your answer.